# Need to check text field in one section of form is filled

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help here.
This is the link to my form:
http://sujdhuj.com/dawood/

In this form, in the survey requirement section, there are options such as: *Office Cleaning, Building Cleaning, Hotel Cleaning,* etc. If I click on *Office Cleaning*, the requirements of the *Office Cleaning form* will be shown and same goes for the other options.

Now, I need a code which will require the user to fill, at least, one section of the cleaning survey  which could be *Office Cleaning, Hotel Cleaning* or any other. If the user doesn't fills any of the section in survey requirement, it needs to show an alert. If the user fills at least one section, the form should be submitted. I need it only for the text fields and not for radio buttons.
I hope you get my point!

Here is the code (I tried to optimize it so there could be some mistakes):

```
<div class="form_title">
 <h3><strong></strong> SERVERY REQUIRMENTS</h3>
</div>

<h2>Building cleaning</h2>
<div>
 <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Building cleaning</h4></div>    
 <div class="form-group options">
   <strong>Interior</strong>
   <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_6" id="option_6" value="Yes">
    <span>
      <span>No</span>
      <span>Yes</span>
    </span>
    <a></a>
  </label>

  <strong>Exterior</strong>
  <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_7" id="option_7" value="Yes">
    <span>
      <span>No</span>
      <span>Yes</span>
    </span>
    <a></a>
  </label>
</div>
</div>

<label>Measurment </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control"   />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>
</div>

<h2>Office Cleaning</h2>
<div>
  <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Office Cleaning</h4></div> 

  <strong>General Cleaning</strong>
  <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_8" id="option_8" value="Yes">
    <span>
      <span>No</span>
      <span>Yes</span>
    </span>
    <a></a>
  </label>
</div>

<strong>Deep Cleaning</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_9" id="option_9" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<label>Measurment </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab" id="id2"  />
</div> 

<label>Description </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab" id="id3" />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr> 

<h2>Resturant & Kitchen Cleaning</h2>
<div>
  <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Resturant & Kitchen Cleaning</h4></div>

  <strong>Interior</strong>
  <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_10" id="option_10" value="Yes">
    <span>
      <span>No</span>
      <span>Yes</span>
    </span>
    <a></a>
  </label>
</div>

<strong>Exterior</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_11" id="option_11" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<strong>W/Facade</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_12" id="option_12" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div> 


<label>Description </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab" id="id4"  />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>
</div>

<h2>Hotal Cleaning</h2>
<div>

 <strong>Flat</strong>
 <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_13" id="option_13" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<strong>Villa</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_14" id="option_14" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<strong>W/ balcony</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_15" id="option_15" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div> 

<label>No. of Bedroom (s):</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab" id="id5" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label>No. of Floor (s):</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
 </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr> 
</div>

<h2>Warehouse Cleaning</h2>

<div>
 <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Warehouse Cleaning</h4></div>
 <strong>General Cleaning</strong>
 <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_16" id="option_16" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<strong>Deep Cleaning</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_17" id="option_17" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<label>Measurment </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Description </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
 </div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>
</div>

<h2>Residnetial Cleaning</h2>

<div>
 <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Residnetial Cleaning</h4></div>

 <strong>Flat</strong>
 <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_18" id="option_18" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<strong>Villa</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_19" id="option_19" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<label>No. of Bedroom (s): </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 

<label>Description </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>
</div>

<h2>Upholstery Cleaning</h2>
<div>
  <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Upholstery Cleaning</h4></div>

  <strong>Sofa</strong>
  <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_20" id="option_20" value="Yes">
    <span>
      <span>No</span>
      <span>Yes</span>
    </span>
    <a></a>
  </label>
</div>
</div>    
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>No. of Seater: </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
 </div> 
</div> 

<strong>Carpet</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_21" id="option_21" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>
</div>

<label>Febric:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 
</div>
<label>Measurment: </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>
</div>

<h2>Glass Cleaning</h2>
<div>
  <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Glass Cleaning</h4></div>

  <strong>Flat</strong>
  <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option_22" id="option_22" value="Yes">
    <span>
      <span>No</span>
      <span>Yes</span>
    </span>
    <a></a>
  </label>
</div>
<strong>Villa</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_23" id="option_23" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<strong>Interior</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_24" id="option_24" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div> 

<strong>Exterior</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_25" id="option_25" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div> 

<label>BIo. of Glass: </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>
</div>
<h2>Water Tank Cleaning</h2>
<div>
 <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Water Tank Cleaning</h4></div>

 <label>No. of Tank: </label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 

<label>Type of Tank: </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 

<label>Description:  </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>
</div>
<h2>Move in & Move Out Cleaning</h2>
<div>
 <div class="col-md-12"><h4>Move in & Move Out Cleaning</h4></div>

 <strong>Flat</strong>
 <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_25" id="option_25" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>
<strong>Villa</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_26" id="option_26" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<label>No. of Bedroom (s):  </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Description:  </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
 </div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>
</div>
<h2>AC Cleaning</h2>
<div>
 <div class="col-md-12"><h4>AC Cleaning</h4></div>

 <strong>General Cleaning  </strong>
 <label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_27" id="option_27" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<strong>Deep Cleaning</strong>
<label class="switch-light switch-ios pull-right">
  <input type="checkbox" name="option_28" id="option_28" value="Yes">
  <span>
    <span>No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </span>
  <a></a>
</label>
</div>

<label>No. of AC(s):  </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
</div> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Type of AC (s): </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsive-tab"  />
 </div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply validation on responsive tab using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881922/apply-validation-on-responsive-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you validate like this

```
if(BuldingCleaning.Selected) 
{
// Validate the textbox
}
if(OfficeCleaning.Selected) 
{
//Validate the  text boxes
}
```

and so on